# Which build to be considered for use when a preprocessor is used

Tags: facebook, blackberry, preprocessor, blackberry-jde

I have a project which needs to be used in 4.6 and 5.0 versions of blackberry.
I have run same code in both the 4.6 and 5.0 versions with some preprocessor directives attached to the code (#ifndef statements which i need to use for 5.0 as facebook sdk is not supported in 4.6 version) 
I have 2 .cod files ( one for 4.6 and other for 5.0)
they work as needed in their respective simulators.

But, when i load the .cod file of 4.6 into 5.0 ... (it treats it as the code inside preprocessor as comment)
and when i do it viceversa

ie from 5.0 into 4.6 ... it says ... projectname-1.cod not found .

A similar question is been posted here too check out where a comment on bbtool says it can be possible 
[One build for two different versions (4.6,4.7 and 5.0+above) in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399216/one-build-for-two-different-versions-4-6-4-7-and-5-0above-in-blackberry)

Comment: You have to make different builds (.cod/.jad files) for different OS to deploy OS-specific functionality. The pre-processors are used only to indicate which part of the code to keep/remove when building the project. For the code `//#ifdef some_condition some_code` if `some_condition` fails then this `some_code` part of the code is removed by **JDE** or **Eclipse** while packaging the project (before making .cod). So, once the project is built i.e. the .cod file is created, there is no more functionality of the pre-processors.

Comment: and if i wan't to achieve it by using Ant .. can it be achieved ?? Just one build

I posted this question in 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442995/how-to-use-ant-in-eclipse-for-preprocessing

please do check out this too @HeartBeat:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using preprocessor is not the way to make `A SINGLE BUILD` for different BB OS Versions** (No matter what tool you use to prepare the build).

Preprocessors are used just to remove/add particular portion of code based on provided conditions before compiling/building the entire code.
More generally, preprocessors are used to consider the source code differently for different conditions.
More more generally, preprocessors are used to produce different source codes for different conditions.
In such a case the scope of preprocessors is only **before** compiling/building the code... **not after** you have build the code and got the **executable/.cod/...etc.** file

Read first few lines of [T](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/SYNTAX/preprocessors.html) [H](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch3-5.html) [E](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html) [S](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_preprocessors.htm) [E](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) links; though these are about C-Preprocessors, but the basic is also applicable here.

Suppose your code is as following:

```python
// START OF CODE
//#preprocess
// this is the second line of the code
//...
//#ifdef OS_5
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.AutoCompleteField;
//#else
//don't import AutoCompleteField and import something else if needed
//#endif

//...
//... // some more codes
//...

//#ifdef OS_5
//...
//...
// Codes for using AutoCompleteField
//...
//...
//#else
//...
//...
// Codes for implementing AutoCompleteField another way by yourself
//...
//...

//...
//... // some more codes
//...
 // END OF CODE
```

It doesn't matter what tool you use to build your code (JDE, Eclipse or using Ant), if you build with the preprocessor `'OS_5'` then (if your tool can understand preprocessors) the following code will be generated :

```python
// START OF CODE
// this is the second line of the code
//...
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.AutoCompleteField;

//...
//... // some more codes
//...

//...
//...
// Codes for using AutoCompleteField
//...
//...

//...
//... // some more codes
//...
 // END OF CODE
```

and the `.cod` file will be generated with the above code. And this `.cod` file will not run on BB OS Versions less than 5.0 because **`AutoCompleteField`** is supported from OS 5.

And if you build **without** the preprocessor **'OS_5'** or other preprocessors
then the following code will be generated:

```python
// START OF CODE
// this is the second line of the code
//...
//don't import AutoCompleteField and import something else if needed

//...
//... // some more codes
//...


//...
//...
// Codes for implementing AutoCompleteField another way by yourself
//...
//...

//...
//... // some more codes
//...
 // END OF CODE
```

and the `.cod` file will be generated using the above code, and This is going to be a different `.cod` file than the previous one.

Now if you want to prepare `A SINGLE BUILD` and deploy it successfully different BB OS supported devices, then you have to `remove dependencies` while coding, i.e. use only those API-classes that are supported by all the OS versions (4.6, 5.0... and others if you want). But it's very difficult sometimes for some cases, because you may have to write your own codes for implementing some features.

It's easier to prepare different builds for different OS --- and on that purpose you can of course use preprocessors..

---

I'm afraid may be I have explained an easy thing in a very complex way.

Comment: Cool one ... Great way ... 
You explain it an way every one could understand

Comment: i need you to take a look at this question too Please 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617804/textfield-error